# duplicated Individuals in the same population

Tags: java, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

I implemented the Java example provided with the [jenes](http://jenes.ciselab.org/Home) library ([Tutorial 5: ObjectChromosome‎](http://jenes.ciselab.org/tutorials/tutorial5/jenes-tutorial-problem5-ocproblem-java)).
I found that the individuals in the population are all the same (i.e. no randomization is happening);

I added the following code after `ga.evolve();` in the OCProblem class to print each individual in the population:

```
ga.evolve();
Population pop= ga.getCurrentPopulation();
ArrayList population_test= pop.getIndividuals();

for(int n=0; n < population_test.size(); n++){
    Individual<ObjectChromosome> individual=(Individual<ObjectChromosome>) population_test.get(n);
    ObjectChromosome chrom = individual.getChromosome();

    int i1 = (Integer)chrom.getValue(0);
    int i2 = (Integer)chrom.getValue(1);
    double i3= (double)chrom.getValue(2);
    boolean i4= (boolean)chrom.getValue(3);
    Color i5= (Color)chrom.getValue(4);

    System.out.println("[ "+ i1+" , "+ i2+" , "+ i3+" , "+ i4+" , "+ i5+" ] "); 
}
```

the output was shocking the individuals are duplicated! 
This is the output from the previous code

> TUTORIAL 5: Find the sequence of colors nearest to the target.    [ 6
>   , 20 , 0.5623470035526044 , false , (RED) ]  [ 6 , 20
>   ,0.5623470035526044 , false , (RED) ]  [ 6 , 20 , 0.5623470035526044 ,
>   false , (RED) ]  [ 6 , 20 , 0.5623470035526044 , false , (RED) ]  [ 6
>   , 20 , 0.5623470035526044 , false , (RED) ]  [ 6 , 20
>   ,0.5623470035526044 , false , (RED) ]  [ 6 , 20 , 0.5623470035526044 ,
>   false , (RED) ]  [ 6 , 20 , 0.5623470035526044 , false , (RED) ]  [ 6
>   ,20 , 0.5623470035526044 , false , (RED) ]  [ 6 , 20
>   ,0.5623470035526044 , false , (RED) ]

Does anyone know why the random method in the [jenes](http://jenes.ciselab.org/Home) library doesn't work on the population?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer:
*I don't have the slightest (well, maybe some) idea about genetic algorihtms, or this library in particular.*

Nevertheless, I will venture a guess:

1) Each loop you get:

```
ObjectChromosome chrom = individual.getChromosome();
```

An then happily discard this information, using some variable named *template* which is not defined in this scope:

```
int i1 = (Integer)template.getValue(0);
```

etc...

2) This guess is somewhat beyond my immediate knowledge: check all populations. Is it really impossible all specimens evolved to have the same genetic fingerprint?

Comment: I edited the code in the post "My bad, I copied the code wrongly ". unfortunately this is not the problem. I believe it's some thing in the randomization method because when I debug and trace the code , I always have these duplicate individuals. Anyway thanks for your comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the rate of mutation is too low (2% if I understand their API correctly).   If you change this line:

> ga.addStage(new SimpleMutator(0.02));

To something like this:

> ga.addStage(new SimpleMutator(0.2));

That would increase the rate of mutation.  It should solve the problem. As to why they have it that way in the tutorial, I have no idea,  but I think the tutorial is a bit out-of-date with their latest version.